# isometric immersion that straightens boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be the the open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in polar coordinates given by $\{ (r,\theta) | 1<r<2 , 0<\theta<\pi \}$. I am trying to find a map $u:\bar{\Omega} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that:

1. $u$ is an isometry on $\Omega$ in the sense that $(Du)^TDu=Id_2$ on $\Omega$.
2. $u$ straightens out the curve $r=1$ i.e. $u(1,\theta)=(\theta,0,0)$.

This is perhaps really simple but I am new to these concepts, when I looked for similar problems I ran into more general cases with manifold or Riemannian manifolds, so I would appreciate if someone can tell me where to start.